# can't load a function In App.js imported from another js file in React/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I want to call the `loadUser` function imported from `auth.js` , but some how the `loadUser` function inside auth.js isn't called. I tried to console log inside `useEffect()` in App.js, and inside `loadUser()` in `auth.js`, I got feedback from useEffect(), but never got any feedback from `loadUser()`, seems to me it might bethe function not exported or imported properly, but I can't seem to find where the problem is.

App.js

```
import { loadUser } from "./actions/auth";
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setauthtoken";

import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
      store.dispatch(loadUser);
      console.log("use efect app.js");
    }
  });
```

auth.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setauthtoken";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
} from "./types";

//load user
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("from loaduser auth.js");
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/auth");
    console.log("inside auth.js get auth route");
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Try changing this `const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) =>` to `const loadUser = async (dispatch) =>`

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out,
`store.dispatch(loadUser)`  in App.js should be `store.dispatch(loadUser())`